# jQuery to highlight keywords in DataList bound with DataTable

Tags: jquery

I found this http://forums.asp.net/p/1390512/2970477.aspx#2970477 as I searched for highlight search keyword in the returned result. But there is no solution or demo on how to accomplish that. I have similar problem like that post. Can anyone help look into that problem of the post above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Let me google that for you :)](http://tinyurl.com/dzwtjj)

EDIT :

1. Add to your css the following definition for the `highlight` class : `.highlight { background-color: yellow }`. You can update it depending on your needs.
2. Include the jquery.highlight-3.js script in your page.
3. To make thinks easy, put your datalist in a `<div id="searchResults">...</div>` tag.
4. Generate a client script that will trigger on page load. For each word you want to highlight, you should execute the following javascript : `$('#searchResults').highlight('yourWordHere'));`

EDIT 2 :

Here is a sample **server side** code.

```
string keywords = keywordsTextBox.Text;
StringBuilder highlightScript = new StringBuilder();

foreach (keyword in keywords.Split(' '))
    highlightScript.AppendFormat("$('#searchResults').highlight('{0}'));", keyword);

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "highlightScript", highlightScript.ToString(), true);
```

We're no longer in the jquery field, I think you'll need to read a little bit more about asp.net application development.

Comment: Can you give a demo pls ? I found this http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html also but it's too generic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying. $('#searchResults').highlight('yourWordHere')); --> 'yourWordHere' is actually a keyword from a label in ASP.NET page. How to get the value from that label and put in in there ? $('#searchResults').highlight(ValueFromLabel)); Thanks a lot.

Comment: I get the keyword from the textbox and store in var and put in Label for later use like : Your result for [label] . I dont know how to get the value from the label and use it in the highlight function. Please show me a way. :D